# SES Email goes to spam in Outlook despite DKIM

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, outlook, spam

I'm sending very simple transactional emails from SES. They always end up in my Outlook's spam folder. I've enabled DKIM signing. 
The email body at the moment is very simplistic, and contains a header, two dates, and a link to sign into the app. 
I've attached pics of my SES email and domain settings. [image: Domain settings] 
[image: email settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DKIM signing does not guarantee your email won't be flagged a spam. I recommend reading [this AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/ses/dkim-troubleshooting-series-deliverability-considerations/) on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

SPF should provide additional verification for emails, if I understand it correctly. SES has it's own SPF records in place but I have the same problem with Outlook and spam.

I also tried setting up the 'Mail From Domain' section on Amazon SES, but again, SES emails go to spam in Outlook. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mail-from.html

It seems the SES server that my emails originate from is on a few blacklists (5 out of 160). Perhaps that has something to do with it.

I can't think of anything else we can do at the moment....